# InnerHTML creation issue, doesn't load in the correct order, possible processing issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

I am using a series of JavaScript functions to load information from a database and use the information in the creation of a thumbnail image and a radio button corresponding to each 'comic' record that the user has theoretically created and uploaded to the database.

My problem arises when the HTML tags are created. While the image and button are both created correctly with no errors, they are outputted in the wrong order. They should be loaded alphabetically by 'comicName', which is represented in the radio button's text, for example:

```
Comic A (img)
Comic B (img)
Comic C (img)
```

I have checked the array 'arr' of 'comicID's that determine the order of outputted html objects at several stages in the code using window alerts, and at all stages the comics are ordered correctly in the array, even when outputting incorrectly. There is an odd circumstance when I have quite a lot of alerts opening up at once; the items DO in fact output in the correct order. (In this case there were around six 'comicID's in the array and each ID had an alert pop up for it at three different times).

I therefore think that the code is creating them in the correct order and trying to output them as such, but some items may be loading sooner than others due to image size or some other processing reason. If this is indeed the case how would I go about sorting it to make sure they load correctly?

Thanks in advance.

---

Javascript:

```
<script>

        // Loads the user's comic list from the database.
        function loadComic()
        {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var getID = '<?php echo $_SESSION["userID"]; ?>';
        var url = "loadCom.php?userID="+getID;


        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {
                loadComicJSON(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

        }

        // JSON parsing for 'loadComic'.
        function loadComicJSON(response)
        {
            var arr = JSON.parse(response);
            var i;
            var out = "";

            document.getElementById("loadList").innerHTML="";

            if (arr.length == 0)
            {
                document.getElementById("uploadTagID").innerHTML="";
                document.getElementById("uploadTagID").innerHTML="No Comics Uploaded";
                document.getElementById("btnDeleteComic").disabled=true;
                document.getElementById("btnEditComic").disabled=true;
                document.getElementById("btnDelAllComics").disabled=true;
                $("#listButtons").hide();
            }
            else
            {   
                document.getElementById("loadList").innerHTML="<br>";

                for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
                {
                    tempID = (arr[i].comicID);
                    getCoverJSON(arr, i, tempID);

                }

                document.getElementById("uploadTagID").innerHTML="";
                document.getElementById("uploadTagID").innerHTML="<u>Uploaded Comics</u>";
                document.getElementById("btnDeleteComic").disabled=false;
                document.getElementById("btnEditComic").disabled=false;
                document.getElementById("btnDelAllComics").disabled=false;
                $("#listButtons").show();

            }

        }

    </script>

    <script>

        // Function to prevent $.get from technically being inside a loop (fixes an issue when loading more than one item).
        function getCoverJSON(arr, i, tempID)
        {   
            $.get("getCover.php", {'comicID': tempID}, function(result)
            {
                getCover(result, arr, i);                           
            }
            );
        }

    </script>

    <script>

        // Function to create a list of radio buttons and associated images from a user's comic list.
        function getCover(result, arr, i)
        {
            var buildLine = document.getElementById("loadList").innerHTML;
            if (result[0].pageLocation == "nocvr")
            {
                var out = "<hr><br><input name='comicList' type='radio' id='" + arr[i].comicID + "' value='" + arr[i].comicID + "'>" + arr[i].comicName + " </option><br><br><img name = '" + ('cm' + arr[i].comicID) + "' id='" + ('com' + arr[i].comicID) + "' onclick='resizeThumb(this)' height='100px;' src='assets/img/nocvr.jpg'><br><br>";

                document.getElementById("loadList").innerHTML="";
                document.getElementById("loadList").innerHTML=(buildLine + out);
            }
            else
            {
                var getImg = result[0].pageLocation;
                var out = "<hr><br><input name='comicList' type='radio' id='" + arr[i].comicID + "' value='" + arr[i].comicID + "'>" + arr[i].comicName + " </option><br><br><img name = '" + ('cm' + arr[i].comicID) + "' id='" + ('com' + arr[i].comicID) + "' onclick='resizeThumb(this)' height='100px;' src='" + getImg + "'><br><br>";

                document.getElementById("loadList").innerHTML="";
                document.getElementById("loadList").innerHTML=(buildLine + out);
            }

        }

    </script>
```

---

PHP (loadCom.php):

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$user = $_GET['userID'];
include_once('includes/conn.inc.php');


$query = ("SELECT comicID, comicName  FROM comic WHERE userID = '$user' ORDER BY comicName ASC");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$outp = "[";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    if ($outp != "[")
    {
        $outp .= ",";
    }
    $outp .= '{"comicID":"' . $rs["comicID"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"comicName":"' . $rs["comicName"] . '"}';

}
$outp .="]";

$conn->close();
echo ($outp);

?>
```

---

PHP (getCover.php)

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
if (isset($_GET["comicID"]))
{
    include_once('includes/conn.inc.php');
    $checkID = $_GET["comicID"];

    $query = ("SELECT pageLocation FROM page WHERE comicID = '$checkID' ORDER BY pageNum");
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {
        $outp = '[{"pageLocation":"nocvr"}]';

        echo ($outp);
    }
    else
    {
        $outp = "[";
        while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {
            if ($outp != "[")
            {
                $outp .= ",";
            }
            $outp .= '{"pageLocation":"' . $rs["pageLocation"] . '"}';
        }
        $outp .="]";

        $conn->close();
        echo ($outp);
    }

}
else
{   
    $checkID = null;
    echo "Error. No comic found.";
}

?>
```

Comment: Probably unrelated to the issue, but something to consider: There is no need to print session variables into javascript and send them back to the server in Ajax. The session is on the server and available in each request, even Ajax requests. loadCom.php should get the userid from the session *directly* not from a request variable of the ajax request. Unless you want to open a security hole.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, I'll fix that.

Comment: So in this case would I change the url to "loadCom.php?comicID=$userID, or do I just refer to it in the PHP script?

Comment: If you are using jquery, make use of it - interspersing the occasional jquery function with a bunch of vanilla javascript makes little sense, unless you are specifically working around a slow or poorly implemented jquery method, and is imho difficult to read

Answer (score 1):

You're using AJAX calls, which are by default asynchronous - there is NO guarantee whatsoever as to what order the responses come back in. e.g. if you have requests A,B,C, then the response to A might come 20 minutes after the C response, because someone's backhoe severed an optic cable somewhere and caused the A request to take a much longer path to the server than C's.

You can switch to synchronous, but that will lock the browser while the requests are pending, which is a bad user experience.

You'd be better off simplifying the code. Instead of doing one ajax call per fetch, you should have ONE call, and send over all of the ids you want to fetch.

In other words, instead of

```
$.get('getCover.php', {id:1});
$.get('getCover.php', {id:2});
$.get('getCover.php', {id:3});
```

switch your code over to

```
$.get('getCover.php', {ids:[1,2,3]});
```

Now it's one single ajax request, one single json response, and within that response, you can order your data however you want.

Comment: That makes sense, sending as an array never occurred to me. I'll post the results once I implement this solution.

Comment: Ok if I post the IDs as an array, how would I then change the PHP file getCover to return an array of 'pageLocation's (the first one from each 'page')?

Comment: do `var_dump($_GET)` to see exactly how they're coming across. then you do whatever it takes to make your query be something like `select ... where userid IN (1,2,3)`

Comment: So something like:

"SELECT pageLocation FROM page WHERE comicID IN (1,2,3) "

Also, I'd specifically just want the first page from each comicID, though not necessarily 'pageNum = 1' because that specific number may be deleted and 'page 2' is the first chronologically.

Comment: To further elaborate the data may be something like pages 1, 2 and 3 matching comicID '1' and pages 3 and 5 matching comicID '2'. I would want the first chronological page in each case (i.e. 1 from id '1' and 3 from id '2').

Comment: that'd be doable in your php code. however you pass in the ids, or retrieve the data from the db, just build your eventual json in the order you want. `$arr = array(array('data from id #1'), array('data from id #3'), array('data from id #2')); echo json_encode($arr)`